# filter json array of objects

Tags: angular, typescript

The data below is the result of getUserRoles function.How do we filter it to check the "associatedAccount": value and then check if associatedAccount value exists in userAccountDto : accountName. If exist or value is the same then get userRoleDTO: roleName value from userAccountDto and return result as result of getUserRoles .

For example   "associatedAccount": "testcompany" exists in userAccountDto": which is "accountName": "testcompany", and then the "userRoleDto": "roleName": "Admin". Return the rolename output as array because

the final result of getUserRoles which is  res.data should be for example based on the logic bove is "Admin" stored in an array.

Thanks for any idea or help.

#Data

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "emailAddress": "test",
  "firstName": "test",
  "lastName": "test",
  "mobileNumber": "test",
  "associatedAccount": "testcompany",
  "status": "Active",
  "lastLogIn": null,
  "invitedById": null,
  "invitedByDate": null,
  "identityId": "2",
  "userAccountDto": [
      {
          "id": 2,
          "accountId": 4,
          "accountName": "testcompany",
          "displayName": "testcompany",
          "userRoleDto": {
              "id": 2,
              "roleName": "Admin"
          },
          "accountDto": {
              "accountId": 4,
              "accountName": "test",
              "displayName": "test",
              "isActive": true,
              "contactFirstName": null,
              "contactLastName": null,
              "contactPhone": null,
              "contactEmailAddress": null,
              "accountRoleDto": [
                  {
                      "id": 1,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Admin"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 2,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Broker"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 5,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Transaction Manager"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 6,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Transaction Super User"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 7,
                      "accountId": 4,
                      "roleName": "Unlicensed User"
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
      {
          "id": 3,
          "accountId": 2,
          "accountName": "testcompany2",
          "displayName": "testcompany2",
          "userRoleDto": {
              "id": 3,
              "roleName": "Admin"
          },
          "accountDto": {
              "accountId": 2,
              "accountName": "testing",
              "displayName": "Bank of test",
              "isActive": true,
              "contactFirstName": null,
              "contactLastName": null,
              "contactPhone": null,
              "contactEmailAddress": null,
              "accountRoleDto": [
                  {
                      "id": 3,
                      "accountId": 2,
                      "roleName": "Admin"
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 4,
                      "accountId": 2,
                      "roleName": "User"
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

#function to get user roles

```
public getUserRoles(): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}getUserRoles`)
        .pipe(catchError((error: any, caught: any) => {
          reject(error);
          return caught;
        }),
          map((res: any) => res.data ))
        .subscribe((role: string[]) => {
          resolve(role);
        });
        
    });
  }
```

#snippet function that calls getUserRoles

```
private checkPermission(allowedUserRoles: Roles[]): Promise<boolean> {
    return this.authService.getSession().then((session: boolean) => {
      if (session) {
        if (!allowedUserRoles) {
          return true;   // if no user roles has been set, all user are allowed to access the route
        } else {
          return this.authService.getUserRoles().then((userRoles: string[]) => {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will filter the accounts for the match and then map the value you want:

```
data.userAccountDto
               .filter(account => account.accountName === data.associatedAccount)
               .map(account => account.userRoleDto.roleName);
```

So you could put this in your function like so:

```
public getUserRoles(): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}getUserRoles`)
        .pipe(catchError((error: any, caught: any) => {
          reject(error);
          return caught;
        }),
          map((res: any) => res.data && res.data.userAccountDto
                                         .filter(account => account.accountName === res.data.associatedAccount)
                                         .map(account => account.userRoleDto.roleName); 
        )).subscribe((role: string[]) => {
          resolve(role);
        });
        
    });
  }
```

So the filter() operator will make the comparison on each item in an array and return an array of truthy items. Then the map operator will map each item and return an array of mapped items... in this case that single field you wanted.

Comment: Hi @jpf , it says cannot find data

Comment: updated... needed to look in res.data instead of just data

Answer (score 0):

```
public getUserRoles(): Promise<string[]> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}getUserRoles`)
        .pipe(catchError((error: any, caught: any) => {
          reject(error);
          return caught;
        }),
        map((response)=> {
            var result  = string[];
            response.foreach(item=> {
                if(item.associatedAccount) {
                    item.userAccountDto.foreach(deepItem=> {
                        if(item.associatedAccount == deepItem.accountName) {

                            result.push(deepItem.userRoleDto.roleName);
                        }
                    })
                }
            })

return  {
    data : result
}
        })
          map((res: any) => res.data ))
        .subscribe((role: string[]) => {
          resolve(role);
        });
        
    });
  }
```